# Disable version column in grails in reused hibernate model

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am reusing the Hibernate model from a Java application in my Grails application as described here https://spring.io/blog/2010/08/26/reuse-your-hibernate-jpa-domain-model-with-grails

Now I have one model class where I removed the version column and grails is complaining

```
Missing column: version
```

Is there a way to tell Grails that optimistic locking is disabled for this class? Normally you would do this via

```
static mapping = {
    version false
}
```

in the domain class, but where do I put this information in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance if this is not the answer, I don't have enough rep to just comment.  I would think you could disable this through the [@Entity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-entity) annotation of your hibernate model using the [OptimisticalLockType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/OptimisticLockType.html).

```
@Entity ( optimisticLock = OptimisticLockType.NONE )
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The hint of sCrain made me realise what the problem was - I had not updated the dependency in my Grails app so it still used the Hibernate model that included the version column.

After updating the dependency the Grails app was compatible with the database again.